# Identificador inválido SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE IndustrialUnit (
UnitId NUMBER (7,2) PRIMARY KEY,
Location_place VARCHAR(50),
Country VARCHAR (50),
FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES Production(ProdId)
);
```

Quando tento definir a FOREIGN KEY surge o seguinte erro: ORA-00904: "PRODID": identificador inválido.

Answer (score 2):

vc não criou a coluna ProdId nessa tabela (IndustrialUnit).
além disso essa coluna deve ser do mesmo tipo e não nula na tabela Production.
verifique.